# How to determine all the isomorphisms

Tags: finite-fields, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

I am trying to find all the isomorphisms from the representation modulo p(x), where $$p(x) = X^3 + X^2 + X + 2,$$ to the representation modulo q(Y), where $$q(y) =  Y^3 + 2Y^2 + 1,$$ in $$ GF(3^3) $$

I believe there will be 3 of them. Below is what I have done so far:

$$ (a + bX + cX^2)(d + eX + kX^2) = (a,b,c)(d,e,k) = ad + (ae + bd)X + (ak+be+cd)X^2 + (bk+ce)X^3 + ckX^4 $$

After reducing the above to p(x):
$$(a,b,c)(d,e,k) = (ad-2(bk+ce-ck),ac+bd-ck-bk-ce,ak+be+cd-bk-ce)$$

After reducing the same thing but to q(x) now:
$$(a,b,c)(d,e,k) = (ad-(bk+ce-2ck),ae+bd-ck,ak+be+cd-2(bk+ce-2ck))$$

Isomorphism needs to satisfy the following property:
$$f(a,b,c) * f(d,e,k) = f((a,b,c)*(d,e,k))$$

I assume I need to define $$f(x) = u + vX + wX^2$$
and express f(a,b,c) in terms of 'u's,'v's and 'w's but this is where I get confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: I recommend that you try and find a zero of $p(X)$ in $GF(3)[Y]/\langle q(Y)\rangle$. Or a zero of $q(Y)$ in $GF(3)[X]/\langle p(X)\rangle$. If $\alpha\in GF(3)[Y]/\langle q(Y)\rangle$ is a zero of $p(X)$, then mapping the coset of $X$ to $\alpha$ gives you the field isomorphism. You get the others by composing with a power of Frobenius. I'm afraid I don't see a trick for finding such a zero right away, so grunt work awaits.

Comment: A plan of attack: calculate what Frobenius automorphism $F(z)=z^3$ does to the cosets of $1, X$ and $X^2$ in $GF(3)[X]/\langle p(X)\rangle$. Only the last one requires grunt work. Then set up the linear system for the three unknowns of $z=u+vX+wX^2$ in the equation $F(z)=z-1$ (remember that $F$ is linear over $GF(3)$. There will be three solutions (it is an underdetermined system), because if $z=\beta$ is a solution, so are $\beta\pm1$. You have just found the zeros of $q(Y)$ in $GF(3)[X]/\langle p(X)\rangle$!